# How to set initialisation value on abstract Django mixin from concrete class

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models, abstract-class

I have an abstract mixin class that adds a Django model field to any concrete class that inherits from it.

At class initialisation - when `makemigrations` is run - I'd like the inheriting class to define whether an inherited field is required or optional via the `blank=` `True` or `False` property.

I've tried various `Meta` and `__new__` approaches, but can't figure out how the abstract mixin class can get the information from the inheriting class.

Here's a naive attempt:

```
from django.db import models


class DescriptionMixin(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    description = models.TetxField(
        # how to get value here?
        blank=inheriting_class.description_required
    )


class OptionalDescription(DescriptionMixin, SomeOtherClass):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Optional description'

    description_required = False


class RequiredDescription(DescriptionMixin, SomeOtherClass):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Required description'

    description_required = True
```

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this at the database level. `makemigrations` doesn't actually initialise your models to create the migration files.

But since you're trying to enforce this on a `TextField`, which cannot be enforced at the database level anyway (`blank` is only used when validating a model through the `full_clean()` method), you could just override the `clean()` method on the `DescriptionMixin`, checking the value of `self.blank` and raising a `ValidationError` appropriately.

Comment: Hi @dirkgoten

Thanks, that's really helpful.

If I was to implement it this way, how would the concrete class model form know if the field was required or not, and show the appropriate "required" class?

Thanks again.

Comment: That's a good question to which I don't have a direct answer. If you're subclassing `ModelForm` you can check the `description_required` property of the model inside the initialiser and set the field's `required` property appropriately. But if you get the model form through a standard modelform_factory (which is the default in the django admin app), I don't know the answer (yet).

Comment: Solved using this (it's actually Wagtail on top of Django):
```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self._meta.get_field('description').blank = not getattr(self, 'description_required', False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using this (it's actually Wagtail on top of Django):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
    self._meta.get_field('description').blank = not getattr(self, 'description_required', False)
```